# How do I pass a quoted string as an argument to an executable in powershell?

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing, external, executable

I can start my application like this:

```
electron ./app/main.prod.js --input `SVGSVG`
```

However, starting it like this:

```
electron ./app/main.prod.js --input '<SVG></SVG>'
```

causes an error: `< was unexpected at this time.`

This is surprising to me since I am passing the special characters as part of a string.

Why does this problem happen?

Comment: @AdminOfThings: No, but Thomas answer did work. Thank you for trying to help!

Comment: Just to improve the answer, does this also work? `electron ./app/main.prod.js --input \`"<SVG></SVG>\`"`

Comment: @Thomas: That works. Much nicer, thanks!

Comment: It depends... Using the `Start-Process` cmdlet, you have more control over the process. Some people might consider this as nicer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These quotes won't be there anymore when PS finally passes the arguments to the program. You might try this call:

```
Start-Process electron -ArgumentList "./app/main.prod.js --input `"<SVG></SVG>`""
```

Sticking to your direct invocation, this will work too:

```
electron ./app/main.prod.js --input `"<SVG></SVG>`"
```